# How to attach plastic (vapor barrier) to the studs?

Tags: vapor-barrier, nails, plastic

What's the best way to attach 4 mil plastic (vapor barrier) to the studs? I tried to use regular nails (sinkers 4d 1 - 3/8'') but the plastic sheet goes off the studs (through the head of the nails) any time I pull the plastic sheet a little bit.

Comment: [Staples](http://images.wikia.com/prowrestling/images/e/ed/Staple_gun.jpg). Don't forget to seal the seams with appropriate tape.

Comment: @Tester101 that could have been an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just doing some repairs on my (Canadian) house and it uses black foam glue (the tube said "acoustic foam") around the edges and nails with an L shaped right angle head along the studs